# Prove that each renewal process with linear renewal function is Poisson

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

I'm looking for a proof that for a renewal process $\{N_t\}_{t\geq0}$ it is equivalent to have a linear renewal function and to be a Poisson process. Since a Poisson process is clearly a renewal process, I'm interested in the other direction.

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that are positive with probability $1$ and have finite expected value, the *renewal sequence*. Let $S_n = \sum_{i\in\mathbb N}^n X_i$, the *time of the nth renewal.* The stochastic process defined by $N_t=\sup\{n\in\mathbb N \vert S_n \leq t\}$ is called a *renewal process*.

The *renewal function* of $\{N_t\}$ is defined by $M(t) = \mathbb E[N_t]$.

Since a renewal process starts at $t=0$, I want to show that:

> Let $\{N_t\}$ be a renewal process with renewal function $M$ and $\alpha>0$ such that $M(t)=\alpha t$. Then $\{N_t\}$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\alpha$.

### Approach

Thanks to the comment, I learned that this can be solved by applying Laplace-Stieltjes transformations. I'm stuck in asserting by means of the renewal equation
$$
\mu(t) = H(t) + \int_0^t \mu(t-x) \mathrm d F(x)\, , \quad t \geq 0
$$
for a uniformly bounded function $H$ and a distribution function $F$ (of the arrival times) that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\mu^*(t) = \frac{H^*(t)}{1-F^*(t)} \, , \quad t \neq 0
\end{equation}
where
$$
\mu^*(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-tx} \mathrm d \mu(x)
$$
is the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of $\mu$.

How do I arrive at $(1)$? If I'm not mistaken, we should have some form of linearity such that
$$
\mu^*(t) = H^*(t) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-tx} \mathrm d \left( \int_0^t \mu(t-x) \mathrm d F(x) \right) \, ,
$$
but I have trouble evaluating the last term. To come up with the desired result, it should evaluate to $\mu^*(t) F^*(t)$. That is assuming $(H+F)^*=H^*+F^*$ which I didn't find any reference to, but it seems immediately from the definition.

Comment: Hint. One way to prove it, is  using the renewal equation and its Laplace transform.

Comment: I don't follow. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Please refer to G. R. Grimmett and D. R. Strizaker, *Probability and Pandom Processes*, 3rd Ed.(2001) , Oxford Univesity Press. S10.1, p416.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got a hold of the book and I almost see this working out quite nicely. My only problem is with one rather technical assertion that I don't see through yet - I'm going to edit my original question to do it justice.

Comment: 1. How to get $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-tx}d(\int_{0}^{t}\mu(t-x)dF(x)) =\mu^\ast(\theta)F^\ast(\theta) $, please refer to the footnote of Grimmett's book--p182.
2. In stead of above (1), it is convenient to use (14) of Grimmett's book, p.416.
If renewal function $ m(t)=\alpha t $, then $ m^\ast(\theta)=\frac{\alpha}{\theta} $ and
$ F^\ast(\theta)=\frac{m^\ast(\theta)}{1+m^\ast(\theta)}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\theta} $.
Hence $ F(t)=1-e^{-\alpha t} $.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to verify $(m*f)^*=m^*f^*$. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: You are wellcome. If you have any question, pls continue to discuss here.